# How to preview chromecast receiver app?

Tags: google-cast

The documentation does mention a preview button which seems to have disappear.

Can I preview a receiver app on the *Google Cast SDK Developer Console*?
How can I force the refresh of an app(programmatically) on the chrome cast ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot preview your receiver on the developer's console. As for refresh, if you mean reloading the receiver app, use window.location.reload(true); you can even call that from the chrome debug console when attached to your receiver.

Comment: Thanks Ali for your always quick and efficient response.